# Add a complex object List with List of string to make a new list and bind to the Gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0, gridview

I have two lists

```
List<QueueListItems> such that

public class QueueListItems
{
    public string QueueDetail { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; } 
}
```

AND

```
List<string> servernames
```

I wanted to add these two different lists into a single list, so that the resultant list can be fed as the datasource to my Gridview.

Comment: They are unrelated, List 1 gets the result set from XML file while List 2 gets the result set from a text file.
I need to show these details in different columns of gridview.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since there doesn't seem to be any relation between the two lists to join on, use an indexer:

```
var result = queue.Select((x, i) => new
             {
                 x.QueueDetail,
                 x.Value,
                 ServerName = servernames[i]
             }).ToList();
```

This will fail if `servernames` has less elements in it than `queue`.

I don't know what you want to happen in that case, but you could test for it:

```
...
ServerName = i < servernames.Count ? servernames[i] : ""
...
```

---

If you just want them all the first line, try this. Probably more efficient ways, but this'll work...

```
var result = queue.Select((x, i) => new
        {
            x.QueueDetail,
            x.Value,
            ServerName = (i == 0 ? string.Join(",", servernames) : "")
        }).ToList();
```

Comment: Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.

This is the error I am getting now.

Comment: Yes, my ultimate goal is to bind the servernames (with comma separated may be) to third columnn of gridview. It is not not linked to first two columns i.e. queuedetails list.

Comment: Moreover, 
    ServerName = i < servernames.Count ? servernames[i] : ""

if I add the above, I will miss the servernames if the servernames.count > queuedetails row count.

Comment: The data to be seen in grid should be like this.

QueueDetail Value          Servernames
Channel         GLO.SVRCONN.RLF  DM1XT, DM2XT, DM3XT, DM4XT

QueueManager NTGL001 

QueueServer U4VMMQSIT0001 

QueueName LO.DAO_RCV

Comment: We get servername list by parsing the text file and returning as a list, and this list of servernames than I wanted to show in the first row of third column in the gridview.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this ?

```
var resultList = (from item in listItems
                  from name in servernames
                  select new {
                         QueueDetail = item.QueueDetail, 
                         Value = item.Value,
                         Servername = name
                             }).ToList();
```

Here, `listItems` is your `List<QueueListItems>` and I assume your two lists have same  length.

Comment: This gives a multiplied result, Each row of list 1 gets associated with list 2, resulting list1 * list 2 results in the resultant list.

Infact, my requirement is list 2 results should be the 3rd column of the gridview.